# javascript regexp exec inconsitent

Tags: javascript, regex

I am seeing a weird behaviour when executing the same regexp matching several times:

```
var r = /(.*)/g
var d = "a"

console.log(r.exec(d))
console.log(r.exec(d))
```

This produces:

```
["a", "a"]
["", ""]
```

Why is it not matching anything the second time around?

Comment: What do you get if you try it a 3rd time?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot it will keep matching the empty string at the end, never reaching the end of the cycle. Normally there isn't infinite matches and after the regex doesn't match anything, the return value is `null`, after which the regex starts matching at the beginning again

Comment: @Esailija, You clearly have an enviable insight into regexps and I know you are right because I just ran a test. However, I can't quite see why there's no automatic reset of lastIndex in this case.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot see my answer. Because `.*` can always match. It will match an empty string, hence `lastIndex` will not advance and the next search will start from that same position again. But `.*` can always match an empty string again. You will only ever get `null` (after which the index is reset) if the pattern fails to match. But `.*` can by definition never fail (on anything).

Comment: Thanks, @m.buettner I understand better now. Your insight is also enviable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is what the `g` flag does. When you use it, exec will continue the next search from the end the previous match. But after your first match (`a`) there is nothing more left in the string, so you get an empty match. This empty match is usually used to terminate an `exec`-loop. If you know that there is only one match, remove the `g` (it means "global" search).

Note that you can (and should) get rid of those parentheses. They just cost you performance. Without them you will only get one `a` in the resulting array.

If you do want to consider multiple matches, but disregard that last empty match, use the loop technique:

```
var match;
while(match = r.exec(d))
    // process match[0] here
```

Note that you only need this loop if you actually have (meaningful) capturing groups. If not (if you only want to get full matches), you can use `match` instead as elclanrs points out:

```
var matches = d.match(r);
```

**EDIT:**

I just realised, most of what I said is partially true but not the actual cause of `["", ""]`. What really happens is this: the first time `.*` matches `a`. The second time the engine tries to continue the search after the previous match (after `a`). Since your pattern has `.*` (which mean 0 or more characters) it will now continue to match empty strings (because they match the pattern). And matching an empty string also does not advance the position for the next search. Hence, even with `.match` you will get `["a", ""]` (`match` is clever enough to abort in such a case).

In fact, if you use that regex with the loop-technique you will get an endless loop (because `match = ["", ""]` will obviously not cause the loop to terminate). But in any case, you should realise that your pattern is nonsensical due to the `*`. It can match anything (including nothing). At least use `.+`. For whatever purpose.

Comment: If you have a global flag is usually more convenient to use `match` than creating a loop to catch all `exec` matches or you can use `replace` as well to avoid the ugly `while` loop.

Comment: @elclanrs global flag used with `.match` doesn't capture groups, but full matches only. Loop and exec is the only way to have it all.

Comment: Yeah, that's true about `match` but `replace` will work fine, and it's shorter and more convenient than the `while` loop which is a bit confusing. http://jsbin.com/owubaf/1/edit

Comment: @elclanrs do you really find that less confusing? I actually think it's quite hacky.

Comment: @elclanrs yes, but that could be considered overly clever by some

Comment: I guess...dunno...I just find it less confusing but maybe it's just me. I tend to prefer more functional approaches than actual loops, say `forEach` instead of `for` etc...

Comment: Plus, one advantage I see is that you can name capture groups however you want and manipulate them within the `replace` function to ie. uppercase, lowercase...

Comment: @elclanrs I guess I don't really like programming by side-effects ;)

Comment: @elclanrs nah, the callback itself is not the problem. But you don't use the callback for its purpose (manipulating matches and replacing them), but to create a side-effect ;). But I guess this starts to go beyond what these comments are intended for.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` returns the first match and moves the internal pointer forward. In this way, a second call will return the second match.

Since there is only one match, the second call returns an empty result.

Comment: the important thing here is `g` though. without it, `exec` would not advance that internal pointer